# Take a proportion of group and spread across values

Tags: r

I'm trying to take a proportion of weight relative to the total when grouped by Fruit and country. Then I want to spread this proportion for the values `Price, Extra_Fee, Total` as the duplicated values are just repeats. So using the proportion, I want to reassign them values based on this.

This is the data I have

```
Buyer     Fruit  Import_country      Weight   Price   Extra_Fee   Total
Rodny     Apple    India              130      2.3      1.10        6
Clare     Apple    India              150      2.3      1.10        6
Fiodi     Apple    India              230      4.5      2.20        20
Reone     Banana   India              270      2.7      1.30        12
Viole     Banana   India              210      2.7      1.30        12
Clark     Banana   India              210      2.7      1.30        12
Simon     Orange   China              260      3.1      1.30        12
Trish     Orange   China              200      3.1      1.30        12
Stewe     Orange   China              290      3.1      1.30        12
```

What I have tried to get the proportion:

```
data_with_proportion <- data %>%
  group_by(Fruit, Import_country) %>%
  mutate(proportion = Weight / sum(Weight)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I can do the second part by following the code above, however I only want to perform the mutate on those duplicated value per `group_by`. So non-duplicates like the row with `Fiodi` should not be included.

I have tried:

```
data_with_proportion%>%
    group_by(Fruit, Import_country) %>% 
    mutate(Price_new = Price*proportion, Extra_Fee_new = Extra_Fee * proportion, Total_new = Total * proportion) %>% select(-Price, -Extra_Fee, -Total) %>% ungroup()
```

But this includes all of them in the calculation.

Reproducible Data:

```
structure(list(Buyer = c("Rodny","Clare","Fiodi","Reone","Viole","Clark","Simon","Trish","Stewe"),
               Fruit = c("Apple", "Apple","Apple","Banana","Banana","Banana","Orange","Orange","Orange"), 
               Import_country = c("India", "India", "India","India", "India", "India", "China", "China", "China"),
               Weight = c(130, 150, 230, 270, 210, 210, 260, 200, 290), Price = c(2.3, 2.3, 4.5, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1),
               Extra_Fee = c(1.10, 1.10, 2.20, 1.30, 1.30, 1.30, 1.30, 1.30, 1.30),
               Total = c(6, 6, 20, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is your expected output given this sample data? Perhaps take one fruit/import_country pair and show what the values should be.

Comment: It is not clear the sentence : `on those duplicated value per group_by` You say that this would exclude the "Fiodi" row but it would also exclude one of the two `Rodny` or `Clare` rows as they are also "duplicated" based on the values included in the `Fruit` and `Import_country` columns. Please clarify this.